# Excel VBA to remove words with less than 3 Chars from a string?

Tags: vba, excel

Pretty much the title says it all but I have been searching for how to do the following
I have a list of approx 100,000 strings in column A

```
"Hello My Name is"
"Delta Tango Foxtrot At"
"bing bong so"
```

and I just need the same strings returning but without the words that are less than 3 Chars in Length

So I will be left with:

```
"Hello Name"
"Delta Tango Foxtrot"
"bing bong"
```

any ideas? as I've done a few searches through the forum and google but can't find what I need

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regex version:

```
Sub removeSmallWords()
    ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1:A10")

    Dim oReg As Object
    Set oReg = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    For Each cell In rng
        With oReg
            .Pattern = "(\s|^)(\w{1,2})(\s|$)"
            .Global = True
            cell.Value = .Replace(cell.Value, " ")
        End With
        cell.Value = Trim(cell.Value)
    Next cell

    Set oReg = Nothing
    ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

Brute force loop way of doing it.  It will be slow for large set of data but will get the job done.

```
Sub removeSmallWords()
    ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1:A10")

    Dim stringArray() As String
    Dim newString As String

    For Each cell In rng
        newString = ""
        stringArray = Split(cell.Text)

        For i = 0 To UBound(stringArray)
            If Len(stringArray(i)) > 3 Then
                newString = newString & " " & stringArray(i)
            End If
        Next i

        cell.Value = Trim(newString)
    Next cell

    ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

P.S. The down votes are probably because you didn't show any effort (code) or problems encountered.  Also, people aren't too friendly when people cross post question across multiple websites at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
Sub KillTheLittleOnes()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, s As String
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction, j As Long
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To N
        s = Cells(i, 1).Value
        ary = Split(s, " ")
        For j = LBound(ary) To UBound(ary)
            If Len(ary(j)) < 3 Then
                ary(j) = ""
            End If
        Next j
        Cells(i, 1).Value = wf.Trim(Join(ary, " "))
    Next i
End Sub
```